# ruby gem mongo depend on bson1.10.12

Tags: mongodb, rubygems, dependencies, bson

I am in trouble with the situation above, my bson version is 2.2, but the mongo gem just depends on bson 1.10.12 only. Why does mongo just depend on bson 1.10.12 only?  Why can't it be compatible upwards? I really need help, thx.

mongo depend on bson 1.10.12 only:
https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo

Answer (score 1):

The `bson` gem version numbers follow semantic versioning, see http://semver.org/ - so bson 2.x is NOT backwards compatible with bson 1.x.  The mongo 1.x gem depends on bson 1.x.  The mongo 2.x gem will specify dependency on bson 2.x when it is released.

So if you are using mongo gem version 1.x, you have to use bson 1.x as specified in the gem dependency, you can't use bson 2.x.  Is there some reason that you must use bson 2.x for your program?

Comment: becase other parts of our app program use bson 2.x, i have some gem file depend on them, there exit the conflict when i bundle install. Thanks for your explanation, I have solved it.